# Why is a line added to .Body when creating mail?

Tags: vba, batch-file, outlook

I use an Outlook rule to run a batch file in Windows that takes as input the Subject and the Body of the email (this means two arguments).

If I run the line directly as C:\Users\me\Desktop\firstplink.bat "subjectPartA subjectPartB" "bodyA bodyB", it does not add a line.

There are two arguments, which are in quotes. I have A and B so there are at least two words in the subject and in the body.

My code adds a line which is messing up the batch file.

```vb
Sub firstplink(item As Outlook.MailItem)
    strSubject = item.Subject
    MsgBox strSubject
    strBody = item.Body
    MsgBox strBody
    strProgramName = "C:\Users\me\Desktop\firstplink.bat"
    strAll = strSubject & " " & strBody
    all = """" & strProgramName & """ """ & strSubject & """ """ & strBody & """"
    MsgBox all
    Call Shell("""" & strProgramName & """ """ & strSubject & """ """ & strBody & """")
End Sub

Sub TestScript()
    Dim testMail As MailItem
    Set testMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    testMail.Subject = "Test subject"
    testMail.Body = "bcTest bbody bb cxcvaa"
    Project1.Module1.firstplink testMail
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the VBA overhead on an Outlook.MailItem appends a `vbCRLF` to the Item.Body if it does not have one. Evidenced by this code

```
Option Explicit

Sub firstplink(item As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim strSubject As String, strBody As String, strAll As String, strProgramName As String
    Dim all As String
    strSubject = item.Subject
    MsgBox strSubject
    Debug.Print Asc(Right(item.Body, 1))
    Debug.Print Asc(Right(item.Body, 2))
    strBody = item.Body
    MsgBox strBody
    strProgramName = "C:\Users\me\Desktop\firstplink.bat"
    strAll = strSubject & " " & strBody
    all = """" & strProgramName & """ """ & strSubject & """ """ & strBody & """"
    MsgBox all
    Call Shell("""" & strProgramName & """ """ & strSubject & """ """ & strBody & """")
End Sub

Sub TestScript()
    Dim testMail As MailItem
    Set testMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    testMail.Subject = "Test subject"
    testMail.Body = "bcTest bbody bb cxcvaa"
    Project1.Module1.firstplink testMail
End Sub
```

The Immediate window reports `10` then `13` on the two Debug.Print's. If a `vbCrLF` is manually added (e.g. `testMail.Body = "bcTest bbody bb cxcvaa" & vbCrLf`) then a second `vbCrLf` is **not** added.

This must have to do with a vbCrLf being expected to terminate the item.body and the overhead adds one if it does not exist to avoid a crash.

Comment: I was planning on dumping large chucks of text this way, and the body of mail would have lots of lines. Is there a way to pass the data through or do i need to delete all the new lines ? Other suggestions?

Comment: Why not create your own class of email varioable with a program name, subject and body?

Comment: What do you mean? The Test script "mail" of course is just an example. I will be getting real emails with different number of lines. I'm not sure I understand your suggestion.

Comment: If you are running the email subject and body against some program, then you could create your own variable with subject and body members. Trimming off any trailing vbCrLf charcters could be made a part of assigning the body var.

Answer (score 1):

Outlook always append `vbCrLf` **at the end of the Body** if it is not already existing.

You can easily show it in your code by replacing `MsgBox strBody` by (for instance) `MsgBox strBody & "_"`

In your example you can simply remove it with a code such as:

```
Sub firstplink(item As Outlook.MailItem)
    strSubject = item.Subject
    strBody = Replace(item.Body, vbCrLf, "")
    Call Shell("""" & strProgramName & """ """ & strSubject & """ """ & strBody & """")
End Sub
```